# By Power shell how to launch a console app and keep it listing in a new instance

Tags: powershell, console-application

I have a simple console app that launches another service. It keeps listing in the background. There is an option to stop this app and service by Ctrl+C. But I have to start this application by power shell script. I tried:-

```
  [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD
  [string]$exePath ="C:\Proj\MyApp.exe"
  $psi = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo $exePath
  $psi.Arguments = "-silent"
  [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
```

And

```
  Invoke-Expression "C:\proj\MyApp.exe"
```

In both cases, it launches the app. But it immediately closes the window or stops the application. There is no issue with the app. It works if I start it from the command line. How to keep it running until user press ctrl+x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not telling the app to wait.

Based on your post. You could replace all of this with...

[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD
[string]$exePath ="C:\Proj\MyApp.exe"
Start-Process -FilePath $exePath -ArgumentList '-silent' -Wait